# Snowflake ST_POLYGON(TO_GEOGRAPHY(...)) Is Inefficient

Tags: gis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a few queries that use geospatial conditions. These queries are running surprisingly slow. Initially I thought it was the geospatial calculation itself, but stripping everything down to just `ST_POLYGON(TO_GEOGRAPHY(...))`, it is still very slow. This would make sense if each row had it's own polygon, but the condition uses a static polygon in the query:

```
SELECT 
    ST_POLYGON(TO_GEOGRAPHY('LINESTRING(-95.75122850074004 28.793166796020444,-95.68622920563344 30.207416499279063,-94.5162418937178 32.56537633083211,-90.94128066286225 34.24734047810797,-88.17881062083825 36.812423897251634,-86.13133282498448 38.15341651409619,-85.28634198860107 38.66275098353796,-84.37635185711038 38.789523129087826,-82.84886842210855 38.4848923369382,-82.32887406125734 37.820427257446994,-82.26387476615074 36.96838022284757,-82.03637723327772 36.00158943485101,-80.99638851157454 35.34155096040939,-78.52641529752944 34.62260477275565,-77.51892622337955 34.005211031324734,-78.26641811710381 31.1020568651834,-80.24889661785029 29.926151366059756,-83.59636031583283 28.793166796020444,-95.75122850074004 28.793166796020444)'))
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>1000000))
```

Snowflake should be able to figure out that it only needs to calculate this polygon once for the entire query. Yet, the more rows that are added, the slower it gets. On an x-small this query takes over a minute. Where this query:

```
SELECT 
    'LINESTRING(-95.75122850074004 28.793166796020444,-95.68622920563344 30.207416499279063,-94.5162418937178 32.56537633083211,-90.94128066286225 34.24734047810797,-88.17881062083825 36.812423897251634,-86.13133282498448 38.15341651409619,-85.28634198860107 38.66275098353796,-84.37635185711038 38.789523129087826,-82.84886842210855 38.4848923369382,-82.32887406125734 37.820427257446994,-82.26387476615074 36.96838022284757,-82.03637723327772 36.00158943485101,-80.99638851157454 35.34155096040939,-78.52641529752944 34.62260477275565,-77.51892622337955 34.005211031324734,-78.26641811710381 31.1020568651834,-80.24889661785029 29.926151366059756,-83.59636031583283 28.793166796020444,-95.75122850074004 28.793166796020444)'
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>3000000))
```

(added 2mm more rows to match the byte count)

Can complete in 2s.

I tried "precomputing" the polygon myself with a `WITH` statement but SF figures out the `WITH` is redundant and drops it. I also tried setting a session variable, but you can't set a complex value like this one as a variable.

I believe this is a bug.

Comment: sounds like the optimizer is not working for this case, I would open a support case to get them to look into it, and try find a work around to avoid this behavior.

Comment: playing with a few methods I cannot force the optimizer to not treat it as a do it first. In the past with things like this even if you find a pattern to trick it, other changes to the SQL can allow it so see the pattern again, and force you back into slowness. Short of putting some logic into a secure view to force the evaluation, or break the sql into steps via a temp table.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I tried a temp table, see results below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geospatial functions are in preview for now, and the team is working hard on all kind of optimizations.

For this case I want to note that making the polygon a single row table would help, but I would still expect better performance as the team gets this feature out of beta.

Let me create a table with one row, the polygon:

```sql
create or replace temp table poly1
as
select ST_POLYGON(TO_GEOGRAPHY('LINESTRING(-95.75122850074004 28.793166796020444,-95.68622920563344 30.207416499279063,-94.5162418937178 32.56537633083211,-90.94128066286225 34.24734047810797,-88.17881062083825 36.812423897251634,-86.13133282498448 38.15341651409619,-85.28634198860107 38.66275098353796,-84.37635185711038 38.789523129087826,-82.84886842210855 38.4848923369382,-82.32887406125734 37.820427257446994,-82.26387476615074 36.96838022284757,-82.03637723327772 36.00158943485101,-80.99638851157454 35.34155096040939,-78.52641529752944 34.62260477275565,-77.51892622337955 34.005211031324734,-78.26641811710381 31.1020568651834,-80.24889661785029 29.926151366059756,-83.59636031583283 28.793166796020444,-95.75122850074004 28.793166796020444)'
       )) polygon
;
```

To see if this would help, I tried a one million rows cross join:

```sql
select *
from poly1, TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>1000000));
```

It takes 14 seconds, and in the query profiler you can see most time was spent on an internal `TO_OBJECT​(​GET_PATH​(​POLY1​.​POLYGON, '_shape'​)​​`.

[image]

What's interesting to note is that the previous operation is mostly concerned with the ascii representation of the polygon. Running operations over this polygon is much quicker:

```sql
select st_area(polygon)
from poly1, TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>1000000));
```

This query should have taken longer (finding the area of a polygon sounds more complicated than just selecting it), but turns out it only took 7 seconds (~half).

[image]

Thanks for the report, and the team will continue to optimize cases like this.

---

For anyone curious about the particular polygon in the question - it's a nice heart:

[image]